# What's the REAL rate limit for Google's web speech api?

Tags: google-api, speech-recognition

So here we are again with the usual bullshit from Google.
They claim their speech-recognition api for developers has a limit of 50 requests per day. But it is evident that there is some other per-minute or per-some-smaller-time-unit limit, because I have been trying requests without reaching 50 per day, but if they are "too close" to one another I randomly get an empty array as a result (and I'm testing with always the same sound files, identical requests).

So please, SOMEBODY FROM GOOGLE (as they say that they monitor SO for questions tagged with google-api), tell me: what are the REAL EXACT usage rate limits for this api?

So that I can adjust my app to those limits instead of wasting my requests per day just to figure out the more strict limits.

Please, only answers from Google staff, and no bullshit.

Comment: You are quite optimistic about google staff reading stackoverflow. If you are not happy with Google, you are welcome to try CMUSphinx, an open source speech recognition toolkit (http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net). If you have issues with CMUSphinx, you'll always get an answer ;)

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Now I'm too lazy to look for a link, but in several places throughout Google Apis documentation it says that the official way of getting support is to ask in StackOverflow and that they "monitor" the google-api tag. I admit expecting an answer _is_ optimistic though, if they don't even bother taking the time to write decent documentation of their stuff.

Comment: btw I'd be happy to use CMUSphinx if it includes enough data (language models or whatever it is that a transcription engine needs to actually work) to be fairly reliable for Italian, English, Spanish, Catalan and French.

Answer (score 2):

OR you could just sleep some seconds between requests and/or backoff if you hit that unofficial limit.

Other Google APIs can also fail for seemingly random causes. You just need to retry some time later.

BTW: harsh language is not making yourself any favor.

Comment: AND if I want to sleep some seconds between requests I need to know how many seconds. I obviously already tried that, and I still got seemingly random empty results. I already know I can go on with trial and error until I figure out the limit empirically by myself. The question is if anybody knows the true limit for sure.