# Is there any real limitation for using chrome web speech API in 2020

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api

I want to use **Web Speech API** (speech recognition part) for a language teaching web application. I heard there is a limitation for requests each user can send to the API... some told that there are only 50 request you can sent to the server and get the recognized speech as text but I tested this and I didn't reached any limitation?

- is there any real limitation for using web speech API in 2020?
- if there is a limitation is it for ip addresses of the users or it's for the domain name?
- where can we find documentation on this limitations?
- why should google use this kind of limitations? it's so sad because they're used to be pioneer in this kind of stuff...

Comment: *"I heard there is a limitation for requests"* Where? From whom? *"some told that there are only 50 request you can sent"* Who told you that? Did they cite any sources?

Comment: The [specification](https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/) doesn't list any rate limits. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API) doesn't, either in that overview page or the pages for [the](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) [main](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechGrammar) [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis). Chrome apparently does use a server for this, so that server might impose restrictions...

Comment: That's the only good news I have heard this month...thanks for the hope you raised !

Comment: look at the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463472/whats-the-real-rate-limit-for-googles-web-speech-api

Comment: It's not an *answer* because I don't know what, if any, limits Google places on the server Chrome apparently sends things to, which would be key to what you're asking. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41563175/is-there-web-speech-api-limitation

Comment: Seems that they're not talking about using Web Speech API on chrome!!! it's not a clear answer...